# How can I disable fontSizes of the Paragraph block inside the Quote block with theme.json?

Tags: block-editor, full-site-editing, theme.json

I'm using theme.json.

I'm specifying `fontSizes` for the Paragraph block as well as the Quote block in theme.json:

```
  "settings": {
    "blocks": {
      "core/paragraph": {
        "typography": {
          "fontSizes": [
            {
              "slug": "small",
              "size": "0.875rem",
              "name": "Small"
            },
            {
              "slug": "regular",
              "size": "1rem",
              "name": "Regular"
            },
            {
              "slug": "large",
              "size": "1.25rem",
              "name": "Large"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "core/quote": {
        "typography": {
          "fontSizes": [
            {
              "slug": "large",
              "size": "1.25rem",
              "name": "Large"
            },
            {
              "slug": "huge",
              "size": "1.75rem",
              "name": "Huge"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Before 6.1 when the content author clicked the Quote block, they were provided with options for my custom `fontSizes` for the Quote block. After 6.1 the Quote block now uses a Paragraph block inside of it, the result is that when content authors select the quote (the Paragraph block) in the Quote block, they are instead provided with my custom `fontSizes` for the Paragraph block.

Is there a way to disable my custom `fontSizes` for the Paragraph block *only* when it is used inside of the Quote block?

Comment: I've pivoted. Instead of specifying `fontSizes` for the Quote block, I've just accepted that the content author will have to choose the `fontSizes` that are set for the Paragraph block inside.

I've then styled the Paragraph sizes differently when they are used in the Quote block.

The downside here is I will need to go in and manually update every Quote block that has been used.